# Code functions differently when used on table rather than un-tabulated cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to change the data in a spreadsheet into a table. The problem I'm having is a piece of code that functions properly in the untabulated version but not in the tabulated one. The code is supposed to go give every cell in a range a hyperlink, then go back through and use a regex to change certain hyperlinks in that range to the appropriate one. The code in both versions is exactly the same.

This code fills in all cells with the first hyperlink:

```
ECO.Range("G3").Formula = "=HYPERLINK(Concatenate(" & """" & filepath & """" & ",if(len(A3)=5, right(A3,5), right(A3,5))," & """" & ".pdf" & """" & "),A3)"
ECO.Range("G3:G" & lastrow).FillDown
```

This code fills cells matching "Dev*" with the second hyperlink:

```
Sub fillDev()
    Dim ECO As Worksheet
    Dim lr As Integer

    Set ECO = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ECO")
    With ECO
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    With ECO.Range("A3:A" & lastrow)
        Set c = .Find("Dev*", LookIn:=xlValues)

    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstrow = c.Row

        Do
            filepath2 = "\\my\file\path"
            ECO.Range("G" & c.Row).Formula = "=HYPERLINK(Concatenate(" & """" & filepath2 & """" & ",Right(A" & c.Row & ",4)," & """" & ".pdf" & """" & "),A" & c.Row & ")"
            Set c = .FindNext(c)
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Row <> firstrow

    End If
  End With
End Sub
```

For whatever reason, when this second block of code runs and it gets to the setting of the formula, it changes all rows in the G column to the second hyperlink, rather than just the one at the current row of G. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Edit: The weird thing is if I insert

```
ECO.Range("G" & c.Row).Value = "XXX"
```

After setting the formula, it operates on the right cell and loops through each of the cells starting with Dev. I can't figure out why setting the formula changes the entire column.

Comment: This would imply that every value in column A has "Dev" in it...  is it possible A contains a formula that contains the string "Dev," even though the result that renders doesn't necessarily contain "Dev?"

Comment: No, there are rows in A that contain only numbers